# What is the purpose of the name argument in ADODB CreateParameter method?

Tags: sql, asp-classic, adodb

So I am working on modifying an existing query in classic ASP.  Classic ASP is fairly new to me, especially this ADODB Command stuff.

As it says on [Microsoft's Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/createparameter-method-ado)

```
Name
Optional. A String value that contains the name of the Parameter object.
```

While the other stuff is also nothing I'm familiar with, those are questions for another day.

```
sql = "INSERT INTO Paintings (pieceName, artistName, description, galleryID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"  
set sqlCmd = Server.CreateObjects("ADODB.Command")
sqlCmd.Parameters.Append(sqlCmd.CreateParameter("@PieceName",adVarChar,adParamInput, 256, txtPieceName))  
sqlCmd.Parameters.Append(sqlCmd.CreateParameter("@ArtistName",adVarChar,adParamInput, 256, txtArtist))
sqlCmd.Parameters.Append(sqlCmd.CreateParameter("@Description",adVarChar,adParamInput, 5000, txtDescription))
sqlCmd.Parameters.Append(sqlCmd.CreateParameter("@Description",adInteger,adParamInput, 256, txtGalleryID))

ADODBCon.query(sql, sqlCmd)
```

Point is, the code is from their live branch.  I can see that `@Description` doesn't match the SQL, so I can figure the command is either case insensitive or the name argument isn't related to the SQL at all.

Second, `@Description` is used twice and still works, with two different types.  I know it says `optional`, but if it does not relate to the SQL, and can exist by the same name with different types, is it just for readability?

I'm sorry if `A String value that contains the name of the Parameter object` completely explains its purpose and I'm just not getting it, but what is the purpose of the name argument?

Answer (score 3):

The `CreateParameter` method is actually creating a [Parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/parameter-object) object which the `.Append` method then adds to the ADODB.Command object's, `sqlCmd` in this case, Parameters collection. Since it is a collection, the name is optional as a collection item can be accessed by item index.

From the documentation on [Parameter Name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/name-property-ado) property:

> For Parameter objects not yet appended to the Parameters collection, the Name 
>   property is read/write. For appended Parameter objects and all other objects, 
>   the Name property is read-only. **Names do not have to be unique within a 
>   collection**.